# Add non-class files (includes folders and files) to your jar using build.xml

Tags: ant, build.xml

I have a java project  (MyProject) with the below mentioned structure

src->package1(read as com.test.Atrribute)->File1.java,File2.java

src->package2(read as com.test.Objects)->obj1.java,obj2.java

src->directory(read as Webcontent.Objects)-> Folder1 -> application.properties file and some more files

Currently the build.xml creates a jar for the above project and copies the class files from package1 and package2.

However, my jar should also include the folder(Webcontent.Objects) with all the content's within it (i.e folders and files).

How can I do this in the build.xml ?

I have never created a  build.xml before and pretty much new to all this.

Following is the jar task in the build.xml to include the class file's in the jar.

```
<target name="MyProject-jar" depends="compile"  
        description="Jar for the Project">        
  <jar destfile="${output.dir}/MyProject.jar" basedir="${output.dir}/">
    <include name="com/test/Attribute/*.class"/>
    <include name="com/test/Objects/*.class"/>          
  </jar>
</target>
```

Appreciate if anybody could help.Thanks.

Comment: Did you ever get an answer?

Answer (score 0):

You could add

```
<include name="Webcontent/Objects/**/*"/>
```

to your jar task

*Note*: The `**` recursively considers directories under its parent

Comment: Thanks for your input. I tried it but doesn't help.My jar still contains only the class files but no directory as in WebContent.Objects and so on.

Comment: Is the WebContent folder under `${output.dir}`?  the jar task will only consider files under the directory specified by the `basedir` attribute.  If it is not, you will need to copy the WebContent folder to the directory specified by `output.dir` before you execute the jar task

Comment: well, I managed to get it copied by adding the following line in the above jar task <fileset dir="src/WebContent">. It thus copied all the contents from within the WebContent directory to the jar...